# Linking msvcrt.lib cannot find __imp__InterlockedCompareExchange@12

Tags: msvcrt, lnk2001

I am trying to solve following linking error for past few days, But I have no clue yet. VS and window sdk installation I guess is fine because there are 100's other projects that are being built successfully. What exactly I have done is; I have made a VC console project and imported legacy code in it and linked it with lot of static libraries. Code has _tmain routine in it and executes on console, i know that because I have the executable some previous build. Please let me know where should I look into

```
------ Build started: Project: s5kcgm2, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
Linking...
MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__InterlockedCompareExchange@12
C:\Ti\convert\s5kcgm\src\lib\Release\s5kcgm2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
Build log was saved at "file://c:\Ti\convert\s5kcgm\src\image\s5kcgm2\Release\BuildLog.htm"
s5kcgm2 - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 8 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link with kernel32.lib (see the "Library" entry at the bottom of [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: Thank you. Project was already linking to kernel 32.lib as in inherited values. However as per your suggestion I explictly entered C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\kernel32.lib in the additional dependencies and it worked. Please let me know if this is correct to have kernel32.lib still in inherited libraries section. And also why it wasn't working ?

Comment: I don't know why it wasn't working before; it shouldn't matter whether `kernel32.lib` comes from the inherited values or not.